# Yii2: Stand alone Action in Module

Tags: php, yii, namespaces, action, yii2

I want to create a directory tree like this:

- models
- modules

  - help

    - controllers

      - default

        - IndexAction.php
      - DefaultController.php
    - views

      - default

        - index.php
    - help.php

So that if I call localhost/mysite/web/index.php?r=help/default/index I should get the index view.

So I created a module withe gii. My Module Class is "app\modules\help\help". I had to use help twice so that I get my module in a subdirectory. ( This is something I don't get. Why doesn't create Yii an subdirectory for each module?)

In the next step I created my Stand Alone Action

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\help\controllers;

use yii\base\Action;

class IndexAction extends Action
{

    public function run()
    {
        $this->controller->render('index');
    }

}
```

In the next step I modified my Controller to use the stand alone action

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\help\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'index'    => 'app\modules\help\controllers\default\IndexAction',
        ];
    }

}
```

If I call now my view in the browser I get the following error:

```
Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
Unable to find 'app\modules\help\controllers\default\IndexAction' in file: E:\wamp\www\my_website/modules/help/controllers/default/IndexAction.php. Namespace missing?
```

But if I go to this Path E:\wamp\www\my_website/modules/help/controllers/default/ on my pc I get shown the IndexAction.php
Can someone help me?

The stand alone action is in a subdirectory of controllers. So the namespace schould be

```
namespace app\modules\help\controllers\default;
```

But that causes this error:

```
 PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
 syntax error, unexpected 'default' (T_DEFAULT), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

**EDIT**

If I use this namespace app\modules\help\controllers\IndexAction in the IndexAction.php I get the following Error. Even if I change the route in the controller I get the unknownClassException:

```
Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
Unable to find 'app\modules\help\controllers\default\IndexAction' in file: E:\wamp\www\my_website/modules/help/controllers/default/IndexAction.php. Namespace missing?
```

And if I use this namespace app\modules\help\controllers\default in the IndexAction.php I get this:

```
 PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
 syntax error, unexpected 'default' (T_DEFAULT), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Comment: Have you tried `app\modules\help\controllers\IndexAction` ? or changing the action's namespace to `app\modules\help\controllers\default`

Comment: Answer is shown in the ticker above in the EDIT statement

Comment: The second part of your edit is the correct way. The error comes from the fact that `default` is a reserved keyword (part of the `switch` statement). If you changed it (and folder name) to something else it should work.

Comment: You are right. It works if I rename default to index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As D.Mill says in his comment. **default** is a reserved keyword. I had to rename the directory and it now works quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong namespacing
replace your code with something like this (note backslash)

```
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'index'    => '\app\modules\help\controllers\default\IndexAction',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Even if I use a leading backslash it doesn't work. That the slashes in the error message are front and backslashes is caused by WAMP I think.

Comment: It doesn't work means, I get an UnknownClassException like in my question shown